# Automator bash unix script, read input files to move if single file or detect if multiple archive and then move archive

Tags: macos, bash, shell, automator

I have a droplet made with automator, which moves files when I drop them on application icon to certain folder.

now script looks like this:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    cp "$f" "volumes/testdrive/testfolder/$(basename "$f")" 
done
```

I was wondering if it possible to do command to detect if multiple files were input into script and then archive them with zip function and move to same folder, and if single file was dropped do regular copy of file to specified folder.

Comment: You might get more feedback if you ask this question on [http://apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Be careful when you use `$f`. You have to escape it. You could write it this way: `".../$(basename '$f')"` to escape it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional, something like (syntax might be way off):

```
if [ $# > 1 ]
 then zip $@ > /path/to/location/foo.zip  # this line might need to be researched
 else cp $@ /path/to/location/`basename $@`
fi
```

You wouldn't want to do this with a for loop, because then it'd go through the rigmarole of creating a zip archive for each file in the selection. If what you were doing was moving each one, then sure, use a loop, but you're just taking them all and zipping them

Answer (score 0):

`$#` contains the number of arguments passed to the script.